# Disable button only when text input is 0

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following code:

```js
var total = document.getElementById('total--input');

document.getElementById('btn-increment-total').addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (total.value > 1) {
    console.log('enabled');
    document.getElementById('btn-decrement-total').enabled = true;
  }

  total.value++;
});

document.getElementById('btn-decrement-total').addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (total.value == 0) {
    console.log('disabled');
    document.getElementById('btn-decrement-total').disabled = true;
  }

  total.value--;
});
```

```html
<button id="btn-increment-total">plus</button>
<button id="btn-decrement-total">min</button>
<input type="text" id="total--input" value="1">
```

The 'decrement' button seems to work and will disable itself when conditions are met.

But the 'increment' button doesn't seem to re-enable the 'decrement' button. Anyone knows why and how to solve this?

Comment: Beside of rearrange your code you must know that the value of input text is a string.

Comment: Where is total defined? Why are you incrementing after you check it? There is no enabled property.

Comment: I edited to actually make the 'Run code snippet' to a 'working' state - BUT, you should be doing `total.value++` and `total.value--` first before checking if `total.value` is `> 1` to increment, and `== 0` to decrement.

I don't intend to `fix` your code though, because it seems that what's more relevant is your misunderstanding of the `.enabled` property - it simply does not exist.

Short answer: you simply just need to set the `disabled` property to either `true` or `false` depending on the condition. Make sense?

Comment: For long answer PLUS a working bug fix, I suggest Zakaria Acharki's answer below - you increment/decrement the value FIRST, THEN you check the UPDATED value to see if you need to set `disabled` to true/false.

Answer (score 1):

There's no `enabled` attribute, you should use `disable="false"` :

```
document.getElementById('btn-decrement-total').disabled = false;
```

Instead of:

```
document.getElementById('btn-decrement-total').enabled = true;
_______________________________________________^^^^^^^
```

**Working sample:**

```js
var total = document.getElementById('total--input');

document.getElementById('btn-increment-total').addEventListener('click', function() {
  total.value++;

  if (total.value > 0) {
    console.log('enabled');
    document.getElementById('btn-decrement-total').disabled = false;
  }

});

document.getElementById('btn-decrement-total').addEventListener('click', function() {
  total.value--;

  if (total.value == 0) {
    console.log('disabled');
    document.getElementById('btn-decrement-total').disabled = true;
  }
});
```

```html
<button id="btn-increment-total">plus</button>
<button id="btn-decrement-total">min</button>
<input type="text" id="total--input" value="1">
```

Comment: Sorry I did asign the input in a const 

const total = document.querySelector("#total--input");

But when I want to increment it still shows me -1 and than the button is disabled. Beside that when I want to increment the button is enabled when the input value is 2. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Have you checked the condition in the working snippet ??

Comment: Congratulations, @Stanley you've earned the **[VoteUp privilege](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow)** consider to use it if any answer helps you, if any answer from the posted here is what you're looking for Mark it as the **[correct answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)** For the future readers.

Answer (score 0):

`enabled` isn't a valid attribute, use `disabled = false` instead

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign the input in an var/let or const.

try this way:

```
const total = document.querySelector("#total--input");
```

Comment: before the if statement**

Answer (score 0):

I had to add an return statement and change some lines of code but this should work.

```
 const disableBtn = function (id, mode) {
      document.getElementById(id).disabled = mode;
    };


document.getElementById('btn-increment-total').addEventListener('click', function () {
  let total = document.getElementById('total--input');

  if (total.value >= 0) {
    disableBtn('btn-decrement-total', false);

  }
  total.value++;

});

document.getElementById('btn-decrement-total').addEventListener('click', function () {
  var total = document.getElementById('total--input');
  total.value--;
  if (total.value <= 0) {
    disableBtn('btn-decrement-total', true);
    return
  }

});



<button id="btn-increment-total">plus</button>
<button id="btn-decrement-total">min</button>
<input type="text" id="total--input" value="1">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to parse the value from the input element to integer before comparing values...

```
var n1 = Number(document.getElementById('input_element').value).
```

Then you can check if it meets the condition